# Visual Studio Android emulator Keyboard input

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-emulator

I am working on a mobile app using Xamarin Forms on Visual Studio. However I am unable to use PC keyboard for input on android emulator. Please help me out of this. Making input using mouse is taking much time and energy.

Also please add info how can I enable PC keyboard on IOS emulator too.

Answer (score 1):

Please edit your emulator and make sure the `hw.keyboard` is selected.

**hw.keyboard:**

> Keyboard support – Determines whether the emulated device supports a QWERTY keyboard.

[image]

Refer: [Editing Android Virtual Device Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/device-properties?pivots=windows)